# Batch Script: Move files into corresponding folders with similar name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script, batch-file

I am trying to set up a paperless practice and store all patient data electronically. I have already created 8000 folders (1 - 8000) and I now need to move approximately 16000 .pdf files into corresponding folders, e.g. "202 Medical Aid Card", "202 Dr Referral", "202 Sick Note" needs to be moved to folder "202". All the files are stored in one folder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please do not confuse this site with a free coding service! Please take the [tour] and go through the [help] to learn [ask]!

Answer (score 1):

If your situation is *that* simple, then you should just go on issuing Operating System Commands similar to the following one:

`MOVE 202* 202\`

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the other current answer to this question:

1. Open a new text document in a plain text editor (e.g. Windows Notepad) and copy the following batch instructions:

   ```
   FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,8000) DO (
       MOVE ".\%%G *" ".\%%G\"
       )
   ```
2. Save this file as ex. `sort_files.bat`.
3. Place this `.bat` file in the same folder as the files you wish sort.
4. Run `sort_files.bat` by either double clicking on it or by executing it from the command line.

**Caveats**

- `.\%%G *` assumes the file name format ex. `202 Medical Aid Card`. If you miss the space (i.e. `.\%%G*`), your files will NOT be sorted correctly and you will wind up with a *huge* headache (so don't do this! =P).
- `.\%%G\` assumes that your existing folders are in the same directory as your files. If they aren't, replace `.` with the actual path to your folder directory (e.g. `C:\path\to\folder\directory\%%G\`).
- In the expression `(1,1,8000)`, the last value (e.g. `8000`) determines how many loops are processed in total. You may want to consider reducing `(1,1,8000)` to a manageable number (e.g. `(1,1,10)`) initially to test your batch file (and check any results) before committing to `(1,1,8000)`.

---

**Notes**

- `%%G` is the batch variable used to count through the loop. It is replaced with a number as the loop is processed. So `MOVE ".\%%G *" ".\%%G\"` becomes ex. `MOVE ".\1 *" ".\1\"`.
- In the command `MOVE ".\%%G *" ".\%%G\"`:

  - Quotes are technically only necessary if the path contains spaces (e.g. `".\%%G *"`) but are used in both the source path (`.\%%G *`) and destination path (`.\%%G\`) for consistency.
  - `.` is a shorthand way of saying "the current directory".
  - `*` is a wildcard. So ex. `.\%%G *` translates to "any file in the current directory starting with `%%G` (e.g. `1`) followed by a space and any other characters (`*`)".

---

**References**

- [SS64.com - FOR Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [SS64.com - Move Command](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. Thank you so much! I will give this a try right away

Comment: Not a problem. Feel free to inquire more if you run into any trouble. =)

Comment: Excellent Answer, @Anaksunaman. Now, what I have been thinking in the meantime has been the following thing: as far as I understand, our KGov has "_already created 8,000 Folders (1 - 8,000)_" **manually** (hard to believe, but it is possible). Imagine that today at 08:00 P.M. U.T.C. + 00:00 their _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Operating System will crash - as it is usually happening nowadays. Then, they will have to create _again_ those 8,000 Folders. I think that the Solution should start from there. They should recursively list them and place them in a Batch File for future use.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Thank you for your concern, The 8000 folders were created in under 2 minutes using a batch file.